# What's the difference between anomalous diffusion and non-linear diffusion?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, diffusion

I'm doing some research on diffusion and I came across these two terms. What's the difference between them? Is there any? Is there any example of these phenomena in semiconductor physics? Thank you.